# sqlite Calculate Difference between current and previous rows

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I been looking for answer all day but can't find any. The best what I did find is function lag but it is not for sqlite. I have table please see picture attached. What I need is calculate speed. That would be (rotations in current row - rotations in previous row). So at speed column row3 would be 6. In speed row4 would be 5. And so on. I used this code but no luck.

```
`select training.id,
 training.tim , 
 training.rotations,
 (training.rotations-training2.rotations) as speed 
 from training training left outer  JOIN training  training2 
 on training.id = training2.id`
 `
```

[image: my Table]

Table name is training.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. Just missed one number at the end of the code. My code now is:

```
  ' select training.id,
    training.tim ,
    training.rotations,
    (training.rotations-training2.rotations) as speed 
    from training training left outer  JOIN training  training2 
    on training.id = training2.id+1 '
```

So just changed from: 
on training.id = training2.id

To:
on training.id = training2.id+1

And result is:

[image]

Don't know if is any other ways to do it. If anyone know any easy way please share. Thanks.